# Keep screen alive and app in front of lockscreen

Tags: android

when i start a google maps navigation it keeps the screen alive and if i turn it off and on again with the power button, the maps app is above the lockscreen and only when i minimize the app, i have to unlock the screen. 
So i can turn the screen off and on and still use the app without having to unlock the screen

How can i achieve that for my own app?

I know i cann keep the screen on with

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

but that doesn't prevent me from having to unlock the screen after turning it off and on again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like the **screen pinning option**. The application will be over the lock screen but it's not done programmatically, however it does the effect you want.

**Instructions to pin an app on the screen:**

- Go to Settings →Security→Screen pinning
- Enable screen pinning and also the option "Ask for unlock pattern before unpinning"
- Now open the app you want, then switch over to the overview menu
- Tap on the pin icon on the app.

However, if you want to do it with code, see the attribute : `android:showOnLockScreen="true"` and the link :

- [Android activity over default lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629179/android-activity-over-default-lock-screen/27718373)
- [Starting activity from service on lock screen turns on the screen but does not show the activity itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785608/starting-activity-from-service-on-lock-screen-turns-on-the-screen-but-does-not-s)
- [FLAG SHOW WHEN LOCKED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED)

Answer (score 3):

You should move
 `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)` below `setContentView()` and put `android:keepScreenOn="true"` into the root View of your main layout.

Comment: still the same. It keeps the screen on, but if i turn it off and on again with the power button, i see only the lockscreen

Answer (score 0):

ok, thanks to the answer given by Arnauld Alex, i got it.
Just add

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

before the `setContentView(...)`