# How to switch on screen on Android when a particular event occurs?

Tags: android, screen, wakelock

I'm trying to create an alarm app which is supposed to ring after a given period of time. 
It works when the screen is switched on; I open the app and the alarm goes off after 5 second. Which is exactly what I want.

Now, I want my app to function the same way when the screen is switched off. So, if I open my app and then close the screen, I want the app to switch on the screen after 5 seconds and then ring the alarm.

I tried `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` (did put in the required permissions) but it did not work.  The alarm rang for like half a second and then then switched off. The screen did not turn on at all. Also, `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` has been deprecated and the documentation suggests using `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` which is useful only if the screen is already switched on and we wan to keep it that way. Not turn it on from off state.

What will I have to do to solve the above problem? Use a service? Also, the screen is locked with number lock.

Here is my code which works only when the screen is switched on:

```
public class AlarmReceiverActivity extends Activity {



       private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_receiver);

            Button stopAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopAlarm);
            stopAlarm.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                    mMediaPlayer.stop();
                    mMediaPlayer.release();
                    finish();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            playSound(this, getAlarmUri());
        }

        private void playSound(Context context, Uri alert) {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, alert);
                final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
                    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);

                    try {
                        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Oops");
                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.out.println("OOPS");
            }
        }

        //Get an alarm sound. Try for an alarm. If none set, try notification,
        //Otherwise, ringtone.
        private Uri getAlarmUri() {
            Uri alert = RingtoneManager
                    .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
            if (alert == null) {
                alert = RingtoneManager
                        .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                if (alert == null) {
                    alert = RingtoneManager
                            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
                }
            }
            return alert;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try adding these flags in addition to your full screen flag:
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

Comment: @user3628775 I tried. The alarm rings now (which was not happening before) but the screen still does not turn on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was dealing with this issue recently.
this is what worked for me:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_view);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

...

}
```

helpful links:

[Android Activity Not Showing When Screen is Woken Up and Lock Screen Not Disabling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979709/android-activity-not-showing-when-screen-is-woken-up-and-lock-screen-not-disabli?rq=1)

http://weimenglee.blogspot.co.il/2013/04/android-tip-waking-up-screen-and.html

[Android Galaxy S4 -- Activity that is visible over lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003568/android-galaxy-s4-activity-that-is-visible-over-lock-screen?rq=1)

also do NOT use dialog theme for the activity!!!